# Issue while using Angular Material <mat-tab> with <object> tag. Every time a tab is selected app reloads

Tags: angular, angular-material

To put simply, my code is:

```
<mat-tab-group>
 <mat-tab>Content 1</mat-tab>
 <mat-tab><object style="height:500px;width:1000px" data="https://www.wynk.in/music"></object></mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

1. Now when 2nd tab is clicked the following site loads.
2. On clicking Tab 1, intended behavior happens.
3. But clicking on the second tab again reloads the site from start.

Is there any way to preserve the state of the application i.e 2nd tab.

Comment: Can you add a StackBlitz example? Take this as starting point https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Unable to save in it just replace the app.component.html file with:
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
 Angular Material 2 App
</mat-toolbar>
<div class="basic-container">
 <mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab>
   <ng-template mat-tab-label>
    TAB 1
   </ng-template>Content 1</mat-tab>
  <mat-tab>
   <ng-template mat-tab-label>
    TAB 2
   </ng-template>
   <object style="height:500px;width:1000px" data="https://www.wynk.in/music"></object></mat-tab>
 </mat-tab-group>
 <span class="version-info">Current build: {{version.full}}</span>
</div>